# golang type.runtime.g not defined

Tags: go, runtime

when i build my golang project by this code:

```golang
go build -tags static_all -v -o bin/output ./pkg/main/main.go
```

i got the result:

```
github.com/timandy/routine/g.getg0: relocation target type.runtime.g not defined
```

the version of github.com/timandy/routine is `v1.0.8`, and the file `github.com/timandy/routine/g.go` don't seem to have anything to do with `type.runtime.g` except that annotation

i dont know how to solve it...

Comment: It might be an indirect dependency of the some  package you are using. Without looking at the code its hard to say which package is causing this issue.

Comment: That package looks to be using unsafe and accessing runtime internals, so you must use a go runtime which is compatible, on a supported architecture and OS. Did you try updating to a newer release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in [`timandy/routine` issue 24](https://github.com/timandy/routine/issues/24), assuming you are compiling with Go 1.20, due to [its linker](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#linker).

Considering the last comment (Feb. 2023) on that issue is:

> Now the latest version of routine supports go1.20.

You should upgrade your routine dependency to version 1.1.1.

---

Alternatively, since the OP was using Go 1.18, upgrading to Go 1.20/1.21 was enough.

Comment: thx, i change go version from 1.21 to 1.18, it can be built successfully

Comment: @ray Well done! Did you also change the version of `routine`?

Comment: no, if change the version of `routine`, there will be other problems. such as `routine.Any` is  unexported `routine.any` in 1.1.1

Comment: @ray OK. I have updated the answer to reflect your solution.